# Struts 1.3: when is better to use DispatchActions than Action?

Tags: action, struts-1, dispatch, struts1

In what cases is better to use DispatchActions than Action?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you need many similar actions with similar form bean in the same struts module (e.g. CRUD actions to `create` `read` `update` `delete` the same object). With plain `Action` you'll need 4 Struts action files with imports, headers, method signatures:

```
// CreateAction.java
package com.example.package;
// imports and header
public class CreateAction extends Action {
    public ActionForward execute(ActionMapping mapping, ActionForm form,
        HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {
        // actual code
    }
}

// ReadAction.java
package com.example.package;
// imports and header
public class ReadAction extends Action {
    public ActionForward execute(ActionMapping mapping, ActionForm form,
        HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {
        // actual code
    }
}

// UpdateAction.java
package com.example.package;
// imports and header
public class UpdateAction extends Action {
    public ActionForward execute(ActionMapping mapping, ActionForm form,
        HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {
        // actual code
    }
}

// DeleteAction.java
package com.example.package;
// imports and header
public class DeleteAction extends Action {
    public ActionForward execute(ActionMapping mapping, ActionForm form,
        HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {
        // actual code
    }
}
```

Also you'll need 4 action mappings in `struts-config.xml` (of course if you are not using [annotations](http://code.google.com/p/strutsannotations/)). But in fact they will just invoke the next layer of code (manager/DAO/etc), which is independent from web (from request/response/mapping classes) and thus testable with unit tests allowing test-driven development and code reusability. All four classes will differ only in 1-2 lines of code. The rest is boilerplate, repeating again and again.

By adding additional parameters or reusing existing one in HTTP request (in other words: in JSP form tag) you can pack all 4 actions in one class, e.g. in `EventDispatchAction`:

```
// CRUDAction.java
package com.example.package;
// imports and header
public class CRUDAction extends EventDispatchAction {
    public ActionForward create(ActionMapping mapping, ActionForm form,
        HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {
        // actual code
    }

    public ActionForward read(ActionMapping mapping, ActionForm form,
        HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {
        // actual code
    }

    public ActionForward update(ActionMapping mapping, ActionForm form,
        HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {
        // actual code
    }

    public ActionForward delete(ActionMapping mapping, ActionForm form,
        HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {
        // actual code
    }
}
```

This requires much less boilerplate. In order to tell which action you want to perform, you can use submit buttons:

```
<html:submit property="update" value="Save" />
<html:submit property="delete" value="Delete" />
```